# calculating max - min within for loop

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this exercise where the idea is, from an array of stock values, buy at the lower value and sell at the higher value.

Example:

```
Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4]
Output: 5
```

Explanation:

Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.

Not 7-1 = 6, as selling price needs to be larger than buying price.

I'm trying to understand how the for loop is working in this solution I found:

```
var maxProfit = function(prices) {
  let profit = 0;
  let min =  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
 
  for(let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {

    min = Math.min(min, prices[i]);
    profit = Math.max(profit, prices[i] - min);
  }    

  return profit
}
```

having the following array `[7,1,5,3,6,4]`,  I know that:

```
min = Math.min(min, prices[i]);  = 1
```

But I don't understand why this line: `profit = Math.max(profit, prices[i] - min);` knows to only subtract the higher values of the array after finding the minimum value 6-1

And when I just type the number returned by the min variable which is 1, like so: `profit = Math.max(profit, prices[i] - 1);` it goes to the beginning of the array and does  7-1.

I hope my questions make sense. I super confused on how the loop is running here.

Thanks

Comment: Buy on day 2 and sell on day 5 has nothing to do with max profit. Please explain.

Comment: @StackSlave ever heard about Stock Exchange? You can't sell before you buy...
AOS, I wonder what are you working on - looks interesting ;)

Comment: @Beamer its just a leetcode question : https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/
nothing to worry about. you're not left out ;D

Comment: haha, thanks for the answer @Claude :D

Comment: Question is poorly asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
profit = 0; //init
profit = Math.Max(0,7-7)//i=0; profit = 0
profit = Math.Max(0,1-1)//i=1; profit = 0
profit = Math.Max(0,5-1)//i=2; profit = 4
profit = Math.Max(4,3-1)//i=3; profit = 4
profit = Math.Max(4,6-1)//i=4; profit = 5
profit = Math.Max(5,4-1)//i=5; profit = 5
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you're really looking to do like:

```js
function maxProfit(prices, startDay = 1){
  const p = prices.slice(startDay-1);
  return Math.max(...p)-Math.min(...p);
}
const nums = [7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4];
console.log(maxProfit(nums, 2));
```

Of course, I would personally go with a zero index for the first day, but that's what you want... I think.

Comment: His script works, only he doesn't understand it.

Comment: That code is ridiculous. There's no need for that loop.

Comment: I don't know if it's needed or not, but your code doesn't work as expected. It should return max profit with the max price index > min price index. He doesn't want to "skip the first day". Read the question...

Answer (score -2):

Read about `console.log` and debugging.

This:

```
min = Math.min(min, prices[i]);
```

is not equal **1**, it depends on the **i**, **min** and the **prices** array.

Analyse output of the script below:

```js
var maxProfit = function(prices) {
  let profit = 0;
  let min =  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
 
  for(let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {

    min = Math.min(min, prices[i]);
    profit = Math.max(profit, prices[i] - min);
    console.log("i: ", i, " price: ", prices[i], " min: ", min, " profit: ", profit);
  }    

  return profit
}

var prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4];

maxProfit(prices);
```